# Connect Conduktor to Heroku Kafka

Tags: macos, heroku, apache-kafka

I wanted to connect Conducktor to a Kafka cluster I have in Heroku and after following the steps from the site for SSL login I still cannot connect .. anyone has any pointers?

1- I go to my Heroku app and on the settings tab, I see the variables for the Public Cert, the private one and the trusted cert.

2- Using the **heroku cli**, I pass those keys into variables and then to files, the commands are:

HEROKU -> VARIABLE (Mac OSX)

```
client_key=`heroku config:get KAFKA_CLIENT_CERT_KEY --app replace_with_application_name`
client_cert=`heroku config:get KAFKA_CLIENT_CERT --app replace_with_application_name`
trusted_cert=`heroku config:get KAFKA_TRUSTED_CERT --app replace_with_application_name`
```

VARIABLE  -> FILE

```
echo "$client_key" >> keystore.pem
echo -n "$client_cert" >> keystore.pem
echo -n "$trusted_cert" > truststore.pem
```

3- I import the files into Conduktor's Java store (https://www.conduktor.io/docs)

```
sudo keytool -keystore /Applications/Conduktor.app/Contents/PlugIns/Java.runtime/Contents/Home/jre/lib/security/cacerts -import -file keystore.pem
```

4- At conduktor, I add a new **Kafka Cluster** using the bootstrap server I get from running the command `heroku config:get KAFKA_URL -app replace_with_application_name` but remove the section `kafka+ssl://` from it.

5- Test the connection and after a few seconds I get the error:

[image: herok]

Any clue will be welcome.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work... Once you have the certs, add these properties on the Kafka Cluster tab:

```
security.protocol=SSL
ssl.client.auth=true
ssl.keystore.password=**<REPLACE_WITH_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD>**
ssl.truststore.password=**<REPLACE_WITH_TRUSTSTORE_PASSWORD>**
ssl.keystore.location=**<REPLACE_WITH_KEYSTORE_PATH>**
ssl.truststore.location=**<REPLACE_WITH_KEYSTORE_PATH>**
ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm=
```